# SQL Table, Importing CSV files turns apostrophe into question mark

Tags: sql, csv, mamp

I have a CSV files with copy that contains apostrophes and when I import it into the database using MAMP, it turns all the apostrophes into question marks. Is there a fix for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why don't you just convert the question marks back into apostrophes?

Comment: They're probably not apostrophes but the curly one that gets swaps in to make it look nice, i.e. [’] vs ['] and the question mark is a generic place holder for character like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of saving your files in `non UTF-8` format such as `ANSI`. When you open a file with text editors that don't support UTF-8 and save it again, this will happen.

Download a text editor such as Notepad++ and check and convert all your (plugin or theme) files to `UTF-8` or UTF-8 Without BOM

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-fix-black-diamond-question-marks-in-wp-321

Comment: I'm a Mac, is there an alternative to Notepad++?

Comment: Notepad++ is, unfortunately, for Windows only. But you can use it with WINE I guess. Refer this link http://studiogreenleaf.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/notepad-on-mac-osx/

Comment: I actually used Google Docs to create the CSV file and in my MySQL table viewing it via PHPmyAdmin, the text looks good, however, when viewing it in the browser, it convert the apostrophes into diamond question marks. The HTML lists the charset as UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Yes, use TextEdit on Mac. You'll find it in Applications

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even when saving my CSV file as UTF-8.  So in Microsoft Word, I edited the text and replaced the actual apostrophes and quotation marks with HTML code (' and ") and then copy and pasted it into my CSV file.  This seemed to work for me.  I used this website for the html code: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

For special characters that aren't importing properly you could try TSQL Bulk Insert and include either:

CODEPAGE = 'ACP' --For ANSI files
CODEPAGE = '65001' --For UTF-8 files